# How is MUI DatePicker styled in conjunction with Formik?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

This code is working fine as far as functionality goes, my biggest problem is frankly the styling. I absolutely cannot find documentation or any other advice on how these two interacting without forcing overrides using sx={{ }}, which comes with problems of its own.

Also, really important note, my errors and helperText aren't displaying properly either.

```
    import React from "react";
    import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
    import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";
    import { AdapterDateFns } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns";
    import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";
    import { useField, useFormikContext } from "formik";
    
    const FormikTextField = ({ type, ...props }) => {
      const [field, meta] = useField(props);
      const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();
    
      if (type === "date") {
        return (
          <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
            <DatePicker
              {...props}
              value={field.value || null}
              onChange={(value) => setFieldValue(field.name, value)}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  error={meta.touched && Boolean(meta.error)}
                  helperText={meta.touched && meta.error}
                  fullWidth
                  variant="outlined"
                  margin="normal"
                />
              )}
            />
          </LocalizationProvider>
        );
      }
    
      return (
        <TextField
          {...field}
          {...props}
          error={meta.touched && Boolean(meta.error)}
          helperText={meta.touched && meta.error}
          fullWidth
          margin="normal"
          variant="outlined"
        />
      );
    };
    
    export default FormikTextField;
```

Use case:

```
<FormikTextField type="date" name="date_of_birth" label="Date of Birth"/>
```

I have used sx={{ }} overrides plus custom css to attempt to mimic the standard TextField characteristics, attempted to remove TextField and find an alternate solution that fits the needs of Formik functionally and my needs stylistically, and attempted every possible combination of other properties that I could to see if any would work all in sync. I could not find anything solution that was within reason (not adding an absurd seeming amount of logic).

**ALRIGHT**, I've got some updated in the spirit of due diligence. My research showed the renderInput() is a deprecated function, so I switched to slotProps() as suggested by MUI Docs.

This fixed my formatting, but I am still having the problem of error handling. Further, I tried to do the same with my Autocomplete field, and that crashed and burned too!

```
import React from "react";
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";
import { AdapterDateFns } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";
import { useField, useFormikContext } from "formik";
import Autocomplete from "react-google-autocomplete";

const FormikTextField = ({ type, ...props }) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);
  const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();

  if (type === "date") {
    return (
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <DatePicker
          {...props}
          value={field.value || null}
          onChange={(value) => setFieldValue(field.name, value)}
          slotProps={{
            textField: {
              variant: "outlined",
              margin: "normal",
              fullWidth: true,
              error: true,
              helperText: "Required",
            },
          }}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
    );
  }

  if (type === "address-autocomplete") {
    return (
      <Autocomplete
        {...props}
        apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY}
        options={{
          types: ["geocode"],
          componentRestrictions: { country: "us" },
        }}
        onPlaceSelected={(place) => {
          let street_address = "";
          let city = "";
          let state = "";
          let zip_code = "";
          let country = "";

          place.address_components.forEach((component) => {
            const types = component.types;
            if (types.includes("street_number")) {
              street_address = `${component.long_name} 
              ${street_address}`;
            }
            if (types.includes("route")) {
              street_address += component.long_name;
            }
            if (types.includes("locality")) {
              city = component.long_name;
            }
            if (types.includes("administrative_area_level_1")) {
              state = component.short_name;
            }
            if (types.includes("postal_code")) {
              zip_code = component.long_name;
            }
            if (types.includes("country")) {
              country = component.long_name;
            }
          });
          setFieldValue("street_address", street_address);
          setFieldValue("city", city);
          setFieldValue("state", state);
          setFieldValue("zip_code", zip_code);
          setFieldValue("country", country);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            {...field}
            error={meta.touched && Boolean(meta.error)}
            helperText={meta.touched && meta.error}
            fullWidth
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
          />
        )}
      />
    );
  }


  return (
    <TextField
      {...field}
      {...props}
      error={meta.touched && Boolean(meta.error)}
      helperText={meta.touched && meta.error}
      fullWidth
      margin="normal"
      variant="outlined"
    />
  );
};

export default FormikTextField;
```